# Set the colour of arrows in inkscape

Tags: color, inkscape

I have added end arrows to some connectors and Bézier curves, but I cannot find how to set their colour, since they appear to be concerned neither by the background settings nor by the outline ones. They remain black no matter what.

How can I assign a given colour to an arrow?

Comment: This issue has been fixed in Inkscape 0.91. It is now possible to change the color of the marker from the interface directly.

Comment: A somewhat unintuitive point - On Inkscape 0.91 as well, this problem still persists, when the arrow is first created and then the color changed. Instead, if the color of the path is first chosen, then a newly created arrow will match the path's color.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Edit: As of [Inkscape 0.91](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.91#Markers), markers take the color of the object. Extensions and workarounds are no longer needed.

---

This is one of the most frequently asked questions about Inkscape, so I'll just quote from [their site](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions#How_do_I_change_the_color_of_markers_.28e.g._arrow_ends.29.3F):

> **How do I change the color of markers (e.g. arrow ends)?**
>   By default, markers are black. You can change their color to match the color of the stroke of the object they are applied to by enabling an effect: Extensions > Modify Path > Color Markers to Match Stroke.

However, this script is an external Python tool, so you might be out of luck if you use Inkscape on Windows or Mac OS X (which has Python, but is missing some dependency). In that case, there is no other way than to edit the SVG source for the objects. Painful!

---

This should change at some point in the future, as it is one of the most requested features (see [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/165865) which gathers progress, or lack thereof). Citing one of the developers (in 2008):

> There's no doubt that this should be the default behaviour, and it's one of the most requested features (bug 165865). But it's a question of someone taking the time to implement it.

and a testimonial from a user, in 2012:

> The original bug was reported in 2004... after 8 years I start to believe I can only make black arrows

Comment: Thanks a lot. On Linux it works like a charm. Sorry to have asked a FAQ question...

Comment: `Color Markers to Match Stroke` removes some objects in my svg...

Comment: 2018 and it still not implemented.

Comment: I'm using Inkscape 0.91 on Linux and this is still a problem.

Comment: In v0.92 they slightly changed the menu names: `Extensions > Modify Path > Color Markers`, make sure the appropriate `Assign fill color` or `Assign stroke color` is checked (Live Preview helps here), then click Apply.

Comment: This is still a problem in Inkscape 1.1

Comment: @endolith should be "This is *again* a problem in 1.1"; I have 1.0.2 installed at home and it works great. At work I installed 1.1 and have to manually go to the Extension menu every time :/

Answer (score 0):

You can select a path that holds the marker you want to match with stroke color, open xml editor and see in style attributes the name of the marker. Then search for this marker in defs, expand to see the paths it is composed of, click for each path on style attribute and replace color code by `context-stroke`. At this point, there is a small display bug ; the markers seems to disappear : modify the stroke color of the path that holds the marker to see it again.

Answer (score -1):

I just draw an arrow in red with **PPT**, then "Ctrl + C" and "Ctrl + V" in Inkscape. And it works very nicely!