# How to create the following arrow in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, drawing

I would like to create the following arrow in Inkscape and wonder about the best way to do this:

[image]

Should I create all the different lines independently and then merge them together or is there an easier way? The problem with this approach would be that there might then be small gaps or the angles are not consistent etc.

Comment: I'm not an InkScape user, but is there any reason why you can't work on a grid and just draw the shape that you want with the pencil tool?

Comment: @Chris: You were right; it is very easy like this to get the desired outcome. If you want, you can post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials on [drawing arrows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0lZKn8bwco), even [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54517/how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-inkscape). Can you redefine your question writing something more about your efforts?

Comment: Sounds like you should search for some basic inkscape tutorials. There are a few different approaches that would work for you, I'm pretty sure you can create shapes without gaps using either lines or shapes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to draw shapes like this is to use a grid and guides.

Just set your grid to a useful size, set up some guides at the correct intervals, turn on some combination of grid or guide snapping and draw.

Take this example of a similar arrow:

[image]

*Note, I don't use Inkscape and the example was made in Illustrator. Inkscape has grids, guides and a pen tool though so there's not much difference.*