# Combining two paths without losing the markings in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

How can I use the Knot Effect in Inkscape while keeping arrowheads (markers) on those paths? For example, here are two arrows :

[image: two arrow image]

In order to use Knot Effect on multiple paths, I tried combining these two paths (following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8SSuAbBOLg)), but then I lose a marker (see the image below).

[image: knot effect image]

It seems that after combining the paths, Inkscape regards the whole thing as just one path and adds a single arrowhead in the end, thus losing the other one. Is there a way to combine two paths without losing the marker (the arrowhead), in order to use the Knot Effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inkscape can manage only two arrows: at the begin and at the end of the path.

Your starting image is composed by two paths:

[image: starting image]

The knot [Live Path Effect](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects.html) applies to one path only, so you have to combine the paths. This maintain one arrow at one extremity of the resulting path:

[image: Path combined]

Now you can add the arrow to the other extremity of the resulting path:

[image: Added both the arrows]

Rotating the image and adding the [Knot effect](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-Knot.html), the job is done. You can flip the image if you want the right spear on top.

[image: Final image]

For a more complex drawing, you can *convert the arrow to path* (see [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54517/how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-inkscape)), and treat it as a graphic object.

Once the arrows are in the desired position, apply *Path > Stroke to Path*. This create a group of paths.

[image: Arrow to path]

Ungroup it, and can place the arrow in the drawing:

[image: Spears with knobs]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! For the last part of your answer, you mean to treat each marker as a separate graphic object? If I just follow Scribblemacher's answer to the question you linked, I don't seem to get the correct Knot Effect.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice trick!

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Combining two paths basically turns them into one path. So, you can just use the Fill and Stroke panel, and in the Stroke Style tab, set an arrow head on both the start and end nodes.

Example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Knot LPE also works on groups. Just group'em (instead of combining).

Comment: Just grouping them doesn't seem to work (the Knot Effect doesn't apply then)

Comment: Maybe depends on the version? I was using 0.92.x (soon-to-be 0.92.5).